# Prove that a subset $W$ of a vector space $V$ is a linear subspace of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

From Friedberg, 4th edition:

> Prove that a subset $W$ of a vector space $V$ is a subspace of $V$ if
>   and only if $W \neq \emptyset$, and, whenever 
>    $a \in F$  and $x,y \in
>  W$, then $ax \in W$ and $x + y \in W$.

I understand that in order to be a subspace, $W$ must contain the element $0$ such that for any element $x \in W$, it satisfies $x+0=x$. If $W$  is null, it cannot be a subspace, therefore its contrapositive statement must be true: If $W$ is a subspace it cannot be null.

I also understand that a subspace must be closed under addition and scalar multiplication. $W$ follows both these properties as stated in the question, but I am unsure as to how to 'prove' this. Aren't the conditions set in the question the definition of what it means to be a subspace? Is it sufficient to state that $W$ satisfies both these conditions and is therefore a subspace?

Comment: There are a few ways to define a subset. The theorem stated is the definition I typically see most: a non-empty set closed under addition and scalar multiplication. What definition does Friedberg use?

Comment: Friedberg uses that definition. In fact it's the only definition I've ever encountered.

Comment: That's weird. Surely you can't be asked to prove this definition? I thought maybe the definition didn't specify $W \neq \emptyset$, but the stronger condition $0 \in W$ instead?

Comment: My apologies. I got confused. It actually does use the stronger condition $0 \in W$.

Comment: Well then, the "only if" direction is pretty trivial. You just need to show that $W$ being non-empty, and closed under addition and scalar multiplication implies that $0 \in W$.

Comment: $V$ is a vector space over a field $K$. Then, exists $0\in K$. If the scalar multiplication is closed in $W$, $0.v=0 \in W$.

Comment: I see. That clarify things considerably. I was somewhat confused as to what the question as asking at first, especially why they needed to specify the last two statements. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

From the question, we know that $W$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. So all we have to do to prove that $W$ is a subspace is to show that $W$ contains the zero vector. 
So, if $x$ is in $W$, and $ax$ is in $W$, then we can take $a=-1$. By this, we have -$x$ is in $W$ (Closure under scalar multiplication). Now, because we know that $W$ is closed under addition, we have $x+(-x)=x-x=0$, which is in $W$, thus showing that $W$ must contain the zero vector.

Answer (score -1):

Is it okay to use 0,-1\in K as we never ask the existence of 0 or -1\in K in the definition of vector space